# How do I find the reverse dependency of a package?

Tags: apt

I was wondering if it was possible to check what package another package is a dependency of.

For example, jetty is mysteriously installed and running on my system and I'd like to check whether it is a dependency of something else.

Comment: The question that this is marked a duplicate of was asked a year and a half after I asked this one

Comment: Yes, but the duplicate on that question has been asked a month earlier.

Comment: @jazzpi The question listed in the closing reason is not closed as duplicate of another question.

Comment: @kiamlaluno [Not anymore](https://web.archive.org/web/20150703114922/http://askubuntu.com:80/questions/5636/can-i-see-why-a-package-is-installed)

Comment: @jazzpi Right, so the argument _the question was closed as duplicate of a question asked one year and a half later so the users can see a link to a question asked a month earlier_ doesn't hold anymore, since that link is not visible up-front anymore.

Answer (score 175, accepted):

You can use `apt-cache rdepends --installed jetty` to see what depends on jetty. This will show both depends & recommends, so you may want to check through the list of packages to see what the relationship is with jetty.

Comment: I misread that as `apt-rdepends`, which I'd already installed. It's probably worth pointing out that they're not the same.

Comment: Also,`apt-cache rdepends jetty` will show you packages that break (and, i suppose, conflict with) `jetty`.

Comment: This helped me, but only the `--installed` flag made it perfect!

Comment: @thor, yeah, it includes Depends, Recommends, Replaces, and Conflicts, which is unintuitive.

However, you can turn this off with --no-pre-depends --no-recommends --no-suggests --no-conflicts --no-breaks --no-replaces --no-enhances as desired.  There is also --no-depends, but normally for rdepends you want that.  There is also --installed, which limits to installed packages.

Comment: There's a slightly different syntax which helped me to differentiate between Recommends, Depends, Suggests, etc. Syntax is `sudo apt rdepends jetty` (Notice it is not using apt-cache but simply apt)

Comment: For the output, why do some of the packages have a vertical bar (pipe symbol) before them?

Comment: For completeness, do not forget 'apt depends' for dependencies in the other direction as compared to 'rdepends'.

Answer (score 20):

Go install `apt-rdepends`. It doesn't only show immediate dependencies, but all the recursive ones, so will tend to give you a large output. So, use a pager as well.

- To display recursive depends: `$ apt-rdepends jetty | pager`. Note that this will list exactly the same depends multiple times. Output of `apt-rdepends` 1.3.0 isn't trivial for scripting as package name doesn't appear along each line...
- To display recursive reverse depends: `$ apt-rdepends --reverse jetty | pager`. Note that this will return all packages, not just installed...

Comment: The OP was asking for reverse dependencies, not recursive dependencies. Confusingly, apt-rdepends and apt-cache rdepends do very different things despite their similar appearance.

Comment: @fli You made me look closer at my answer, and I have corrected it. Thanks.

Comment: It shows more info than `apt rdepends`.

Answer (score 7):

If you open Synaptic and find the package, you can right click on it and select Properties.
Under the tab Dependencies you can see the packages that jetty depend on, and which packages is dependent on jetty (the dropdown list).