# run.x86-linux always at 100% CPU

Tags: cpu-load

I have my computers left open for 2 days. The last few hours when running the `top` command I get back these results:

```
top - 20:51:39 up 1 day,  7:22,  4 users,  load average: 1.38, 1.64, 1.53
Tasks: 179 total,   2 running, 173 sleeping,   0 stopped,   4 zombie
Cpu(s):100.0%us,  0.0%sy,  0.0%ni,  0.0%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Mem:   1017176k total,   792072k used,   225104k free,    44676k buffers
Swap:  1614492k total,   197084k used,  1417408k free,   325896k cached
 Unknown command - try 'h' for help 
  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND                                             
20925 monra     20   0 17252  11m  548 R  103  1.1  16:26.47 run.x86-linux                                       
22095 monra     20   0  2548 1240  924 R  103  0.1   0:00.02 top                                                 
    1 root      20   0  2800 1144  740 S    0  0.1   0:00.80 init
```

As you see the program `run.x86-linux` is eating 100% CPU. Why is this? Is there any way to fix it without restarting the computer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The file `run.x86-linux` is part of the [smlnj-runtime](http://packages.ubuntu.com/natty/smlnj-runtime) package, which [is a dependency of](https://askubuntu.com/questions/13296/how-do-i-find-the-reverse-dependency-of-a-package):

- smlnj
- ml-yacc
- ml-lex

Focus on troubleshooting these applications.

Keep an eye on `watch "ps -C run.x86-linux -o pcpu,pid,start_time,command"` while you use them, and see if you can devise a series of steps that will reliably cause the runaway CPU usage.

If you think you have found a bug that is not the result of your own programming activities, file a bug report [against the runaway process](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs#Collecting%20information%20from%20a%20currently%20running%20program) and change the "In what package did you find this bug?" field to the package for the application that is causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Press `k` to kill the program.  More importantly, what is this program and where did you get it from?  It smells like some malware you downloaded from a bad web site.

Comment: It could be from here: http://sysinf0.klabs.be/usr/lib/smlnj/bin/.run/run.x86-linux?dist=;arch= although I have closed SML/NJ a long time ago