# How to list dependent packages (reverse dependencies)?

Tags: package-management, command-line, dependencies

In order to research what caused the installation of a given package, I'd like to get a list of packages which depend on that package. I couldn't find anything obvious in `man dpkg`.

Comment: Related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/13296/how-do-i-find-the-reverse-dependency-of-a-package

Comment: The older question's answers all revolve around `aptitude`, something that hasn't been installed by default for years. In 2017, everyone on Ubuntu still has `apt-cache`. Anyone who follows the linked question is going to get lost in a discussion about a program few will have.

Answer (score 482, accepted):

`apt-cache rdepends packagename` should do what you want.

To limit it to packages that are installed on your system: `apt-cache rdepends --installed packagename`

Comment: Excellent! `apt-cache rdepends tofrodos` confirmed the [suspicion](http://superuser.com/questions/52044/convert-crlfs-to-line-feeds-on-linux) that it was installed by another package (the obsoleted `dos2unix`).

Comment: Good deal. I do wish there was a recursive option. Sadly there is not as far as I am aware.

Comment: As for today (apt version 0.9.9.1), there is --recurse option that works with rdepends.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up.  /me is even more pleased than he was.

Comment: @l0b0: btw, if you only needed to know if a package was installed automatically as a dependency - there is `apt-mark showauto` available

Comment: If you add `--installed`, the output is even useful for packages which can be used by many others: `apt-cache rdepends --installed packagename`

Comment: There's a slightly different syntax which helped me to differentiate between Recommends, Depends, Suggests, etc. Syntax is `sudo apt rdepends packagename` (Notice it is not using apt-cache but simply apt)

Comment: For the output, why do some of the packages have a vertical bar (pipe symbol) before them?

Comment: The command `apt-cache rdepends packagename` seem not to work in WSL.

Comment: That sounds like a them problem not a me problem.  It works on native systems.

Comment: Unfortunately, the list is not sorted alphabetically (unlike the result of `apt-rdepends --reverse <package name>`) and includes reverse dependencies that aren’t installed by default (which I consider strange for a command with “cache” in the name). To address those issues, one can use `apt-cache rdepends --installed <package name> | tail --lines=+3 | sort`. (The `tail` command is used to strip the two heading lines, which must be done before the sort occurs.)

Comment: To add to the comment by @VahidPazirandeh: `apt` does not need `sudo` for operations like `rdepends`. Just `apt rdepends packagename` suffices.

Comment: @quazgar Unfortunately, `--installed` does not work as one may think and is rather useless. See [my answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1451755/691424).

Comment: Thanks. It seems to repeat dependencies though, so I used it as: `apt-cache rdepends texlive-latex-extra | tail -n +3 | sort | uniq`.

Answer (score 96):

aptitude has a fairly nice way of handling this:

```
$ aptitude why bash
i   foomatic-filters PreDepends bash (>= 2.05)
```

By default, it only lists the "most installed, strongest, tightest, shortest" reason, but you can use `aptitude -v why` to make it output everything it finds.

Comment: Seems like it considers only the installed packages, not everything available. And that was what I needed.

Comment: For that you want `reverse-depends` in `ubuntu-dev-tools`

Comment: How about debian?

Comment: `ubuntu-dev-tools` is in Debian

Comment: This is great. I learned that `openssh-server` *recommended* (and therefore installed) `xauth` on a headless server, dragging in *hundreds* of x11 dependencies and dozens of useless updates a month. That's the problem with automated package management!

Comment: I've found this the best way to figure out long and complex reverse dependencies. It does require installing `sudo apt install aptitude`, but it's really worth it. Helpe my know why `ubuntu-unity-desktop` ended up pulling `mysql-common`!

Comment: Worth noting that the `--recurse` option is useful too. As in `apt rdepends --recurse packagename`

Answer (score 42):

The simplest option is still:

```
apt rdepends package-name
```

which does not require you to install any package.

Comment: What is this adding to the accepted answer?

Comment: The accepted answer has nothing to do with this one. The output is *completely* different and way more useful for human consumption than apt-cache's. The answer mentions that apt-cache is not installed by default everywhere - that alone should be a rather good hint why this answer has its purpose. finally, this is actually the answer I was looking for, so any downvote is rather silly.

Comment: One very significant reason why this is better than the accepted version is that it includes the _version_ of the dependencies, unlike `apt-cache`s output. It's exactly what I needed right now (debugging a glibc 2.28 incompatibility, so upvoting)

Comment: upvote for using just apt.  at the time of the original answer, I'm not sure this just apt solution would have been valid, but if it is now, that's good.

Answer (score 35):

```
apt-cache showpkg <pkgname>
```

Example:

```
apt-cache showpkg lightdm
```

Comment: This is actually still the correct syntax for `apt-cache`.  Just tried `apt showpkg xorg` and got `E: Invalid operation showpkg`

Comment: This did the trick!!!

Answer (score 19):

There is more than one way, with each method showing a different output.

For a detailed view of the full reverse dependency tree;

```
aptitude install apt-rdepends
apt-rdepends -r bash
```

Alternatively;

```
apt-cache showpkg bash
```

Or a concise list:

```
apt-cache rdepends bash
```

Comment: What exactly does `rdepends` show in that tree? `apt-rdepends php7.0-fpm` shows `sed`. `sed` doesn't depend on PHP, let alone PHP FPM.

Comment: It is reverse depends, it means that PHP depends on sed.

Comment: Hi guys, actually "apt-rdepends" stands for "recursive dependency". If you want reverse recursive dependency, you have to type : `apt-rdepends -r yourPackageNameHere`

Comment: The apt-cache man page says "rdepends shows a listing of each reverse dependency a package has". Whereas apt-rdepends requires the -r option to do reverse dependencies, as @SebMa says.

Answer (score 18):

In addition to other good answers, an `apt/apt-get -s` does a "simulated" removal (or install).

```
sudo apt -s remove <pkgname>
```

Using `-s` or `--simulate` to remove (or install) packages, will normally list any dependencies affected. It will show orphaned packages when removing, or needed dependencies when installing, without actually executing the `install` or `remove`. Informational only.

Comment: `apt remove -s php7.0-fpm` shows `The following additional packages will be installed:
  apache2 apache2-bin apache2-data libapache2-mod-php7.0 libaprutil1-dbd-sqlite3 libaprutil1-ldap liblua5.1-0`. Why would apache get installed if I remove PHP FPM?

Comment: @DanDascalescu Hmm. Might be a bad install/remove script for apt pkg or might be you have some other dependencies that install apache2 as dep (meaning a webserver is needed - and I believe apache2 is default web server). Could be a few things. Just not sure. Has the smell of a good post on AskUbuntu if you haven't found an answer.

Answer (score 2):

With the `reverse-depends` command from the package: [`ubuntu-dev-tools`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/impish/ubuntu-dev-tools)

```sh
reverse-depends libjs-openlayers
# For build depends search
reverse-depends -b libjs-openlayers
```

```
Reverse-Recommends
* gis-osm

Reverse-Depends
* cyclograph
* phpmyadmin
* sumo-tools

Packages without architectures listed are reverse-dependencies in: amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, ppc64el, s390x
```

Answer (score 2):

Since the `--installed` option of `apt-cache` was mentioned in comments of [RobotHumans's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/128527/691424) and does not make much sense as the matching is done against all versions, including uninstalled ones (see [Debian bug 1029586](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=1029586)), here's the solution proposed by Julian Andres Klode to get the reverse dependencies among the installed packages:

```
apt list '?any-version(?installed?depends(?exact-name(packagename)))'
```

Note that `packagename` is just the package name, without architecture information. For instance, `libpcre3` works, but not `libpcre3:amd64`.