# How can I find all packages that depends on another?

Tags: apt-cache

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to list package dependees (reverse dependencies)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/128524/how-to-list-package-dependees-reverse-dependencies)

I want to find all the packages in the Ubuntu repository that depends on one particular package. In this case I want that dependency to be `libqt4-dev`, so I can find all the packages developed with Qt. I know I need to use `apt-cache`, but I'm not sure what the arguments should be.

Comment: Looking for reverse dependencies of `libqt4-dev` will not show you what packages are developed with Qt. `-dev` packages provide header files. You would see `libqt4-dev` to *compile* programs that are developed with Qt4--you would not need it to *install* them from binary packages.

Answer (score 1):

You should get used to using `man`. Hence,

> $ man apt-cache

reveals

> showpkg pkg...
>
> showpkg displays information about the packages listed on the command line. Remaining arguments are package names. The available versions and reverse dependencies of each package listed are listed, as well as forward dependencies for each version. Forward (normal) dependencies are those packages upon which the package in question depends; reverse dependencies are those packages that depend upon the package in question.

Hence the command you are after is `apt-cache showpkg libqt4-dev`.

Comment: I've tried `showpkg`, but it doesn't seem to list everything. KDE is built on Qt, but there's no K* apps in there.

Comment: I assume either you'd probably have to follow the inheritance of dependencies further, or perhaps it's a different package(s) that KDE uses? e.g. I can see plenty of KDE if I try `apt-cache showpkg libqt4-dbus`.