# What's the equivalent of "rpm -q whatrequires"?

Tags: deb

Wonder that I could not find the deb equivalent of

```
rpm -q whatrequires <installed package>
```

All I can find is either the equivalent of rpm -q requires or the whatrequires for a yet to be installed deb package.

If this is already answered please accept my appologies and point me to the right place.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're looking for `apt-cache rdepends <package>` which will list all packages with a dependency on `<package>`. Normally this shows all packages, whether installed or not - `apt-cache rdepends --installed <package>` restricts the results to installed packages.

A search finds other [similar questions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/128524/how-to-list-package-dependees-reverse-dependencies), but since none of them make a comparison to `rpm`, I don't think this is a duplicate.