# 'E:The package libmagickcore4-extra needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.'

Tags: upgrade, apt, updates, package-management

I was going to upgrade from 12.04 to 12.10 and skipped the update for libmagickcore4-extra, and some problem occurred, and the upgrade stopped. Now, whenever I try and open the Software update, I get this message:

```
Could not initialize the package information

An unresolvable problem occurred while initializing the package information.
Please report this bug against the 'update-manager' package and include the following error message:
'E:The package libmagickcore4-extra needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it'
```

I tried finding a solution on
[How do I resolve unmet dependencies after adding a PPA?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies)
but with no luck.

The terminal gives the same error message.

Please Help!!

Answer (score 2):

In Ubuntu >= 12.10 **limagickcore4** was replaced by **libmagickcore5**. This should however be resolved with your release upgrade after you had regularly installed [imagemagick](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/imagemagick) [image: Install imagemagick] from the repositories.

In case you had it installed from ppa or locally you need to deactivate the ppa and manually purge this package before you can reinstall imagemagick.

It may also be that you manually had installed another package which depends on `libmagickcore4`. You will have to remove/upgrade this package first before you can proceed.

Comment: i just opened ubuntu after about 6 months ... i updated everything that i could through the software centre ... then when i went on to upgrade ubuntu from 12.04 to 12.10 .. this happened ... if the file was replaced by libmagickcore5, why is it asking me to reinstall core4 ... it doesnt make sense .... ubuntu software centre,software update dont run ... so i downloaded a package from one of the websites .. but i cant seen to get my head around the package ...

Answer (score 1):

As Takkat mentioned, the **limagickcore4** was replaced by **libmagickcore5** in the official repositories for Ubuntu. You may check which versions you can install using the `apt-cache` command.

```
$ apt-cache search libmagick
```

You may try to [find which packages depends on **limagickcore4**](https://askubuntu.com/questions/128524/how-to-list-dependent-packages-reverse-dependencies) and remove them.

```
$ apt-cache rdepends --installed libmagickcore4-extra
```

However, sometimes it is hard to determine which packages that depend on libmagickcore4 can be uninstalled or replaced. You may try `aptitude` to find a solution. When you run the program, it shows you multiple solutions that may imply to install, downgrade, upgrade or remove multiple packages.

```
$ sudo aptitude
```