# How To Download APT And All It's Dependencies?

Tags: apt

I'm trying to download APT and all it's dependencies so I can use dpkg to install APT offline. Since you can't simply use `apt-get download apt` the approach I've taken is trying to generate a list of dependencies which I can then manually use `apt-get download package-name` to retrieve.

**I've tried these:**

`apt-cache showpkg package-name`

- Source: [How can I check dependency list for a deb package](https://askubuntu.com/questions/80655/how-can-i-check-dependency-list-for-a-deb-package)

`apt-cache depends packagename`

- Source: [How to find top-level dependencies in a list of deb packages?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/422726/how-to-find-top-level-dependencies-in-a-list-of-deb-packages)

`dpkg -I pkg-name1_version.deb`

- Source: [How to find all dependent (dependency walker) packages before installing a .deb file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/432283/how-to-find-all-dependent-dependency-walker-packages-before-installing-a-deb)

They don't work properly. I need a way to list not only the dependencies of APT, but also the dependency dependencies; the entire tree. According to "`sudo apt-get install apt --reinstall`" APT has 302 depenencies+sub-depenencies. The lists generated using the answers I've found appear only to list the first level of dependencies, because they are too short.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13756800/how-to-download-all-dependencies-and-packages-to-directory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either I am gravely mistaken, or there's something fundamentally wrong with `apt` having 302 dependencies + sub-dependencies. How can any distribution claim to lightweight if it depends on `apt`, then? At least, in my laptop, reinstalling `apt` doesn't mention any dependencies at all, so I am not sure where you got that figure from. I cooked up [a script](http://paste.ubuntu.com/7757661/) to check. On Ubuntu 14.04, I get 24 dependencies:

```
dpkg gcc-4.8-base gcc-4.9-base gnupg gpgv install-info libacl1 libapt-pkg4.12 libattr1 libbz2-1.0 libc6 libgcc1 liblzma5 libpcre3 libreadline6 libselinux1 libstdc++6 libtinfo5 libusb-0.1-4 multiarch-support readline-common tar ubuntu-keyring zlib1g
```

I then learned about `apt-rdepends`: http://xmodulo.com/2013/07/how-to-check-package-dependencies-on-ubuntu-or-debian.html

I installed and ran it, filtered the dependencies, sorted and compared to find the same list I got with the script. So I can safely conclude that these are all the packages you need to install `apt`. I think one of those `gcc-4.[89]` can be ignored depending on which one you want to install. Note that this list has trimmed down from Ubuntu 12.04, on which running this script (on a server) gave me 28 dependencies:

```
coreutils debconf dpkg gcc-4.6-base gnupg gpgv install-info libacl1 libapt-pkg4.12 libattr1 libbz2-1.0 libc6 libc-bin libgcc1 liblzma5 libreadline6 libselinux1 libstdc++6 libtinfo5 libusb-0.1-4 multiarch-support perl-base readline-common tar tzdata ubuntu-keyring xz-utils zlib1g
```

Presumably the packages have been trimmed down. The lack of dependency on `coreutils` and `debconf` is startling, I must say.

On a side note, I agree with this bug given in `apt-rdepends` man page:

```
  apt-rdepends exists.  This functionality should really reside in apt-
   cache itself.
```

The `apt-cache` tool provides four relevant commands that [Braiam](https://askubuntu.com/users/169736/braiam), [unorthodox-grammar](https://askubuntu.com/users/250271/unorthodox-grammar) and I have discussed:

- `depends`: List the (forward) dependencies. This also includes all the packages that are recommended, and also includes packages in the *Breaks*, *Conflicts* and *Replaces* sections. We just need to look at the *Depends* and *Pre-Depends* packages.
- `rdepends`: There's an unfortunate naming clash with `apt-rdepends`. Both `apt-rdepends` and my aforementioned script check for dependencies **r***ecursively*, whereas the `apt-cache` command is looking for **r***everse* dependencies - packages which depend on the package in consideration. Use this command to check for potentially breakages caused by a package depending on a specific version of the one you are going got change.
- `showsrc`: This command gives information about the source package that was use to build a package. A single source package can be used to build multiple binary packages - each of which may or may not depend on the others. `apt`, for example, depends on `libapt-pkg`, but not on `libapt-inst`, both of which are provided by the [`apt` source package](http://packages.ubuntu.com/source/precise/apt). Use this command to gain some insight into other packages you should install, which may not be dependencies, but which may be needed for greater utility,
- `showpkg`: This command, among other things, lists both reverse and forward dependencies. The reverse dependencies are listed in a straightforward list, but the forward ones are a bit of a jumble - I still am not sure what the numbers mean. In any case, the individual commands `depends` and `rdepends` are clearer.

Thus, if we need to look at *all* the packages that a package might depend on directly or indirectly, `apt-rdepends` is what we need.

Comment: "<code>apt-rdepends apt</code>" gives me 28 packages, "<code>apt-cache rdepends apt</code>"
gives me 54 packages, and @Braiam's suggestion about "<code>apt-cache showsrc apt</code>" lists 
"libapt-inst1.5" while neither of the above do. Every tool seems to have a different opinion???

Comment: `apt-cache rdepends` is looking for *Reverse dependencies*, my script and `apt-rdepends` are *recursively* looking for dependencies. `libapt-inst1.5` is a package provided by the source package `apt`, which is different from the binary package `apt`. `apt` binary package may or may not depend on anything else provided by the `apt` source package (it depends on at least one). Thus, it is a sibling in the dependency relationship, not a parent or a child. That said, you should install the four packages mentioned by @Braiam, using `apt-rdepends` to find the dependencies of all four.

Comment: @unorthodoxgrammar see http://packages.ubuntu.com/source/precise/apt for the source package and a list of binary packages compiled from it. You can probably use the source packages and its build-depends to build the packages on the target system.

Comment: "apt-cache showpkg apt" lists packages that aren't in the previous methods.

Comment: @unorthodoxgrammar `showpkg` lists all the packages listed by `depends` and `rdepends`. You can immediately tell which ones are the reverse dependencies. The dependencies list includes *suggests*, *recommends*, *breaks* and *conflicts* packages as well, using numbers in the parenthesis to indicate the status, which are listed in a much cleaner way in `depends `, so that you can filter out the unnecessary bits. It doesn't add any new information that I can see.

Answer (score 2):

There are only 4 packages which you should to be preoccupated with: `libapt-pkg4.12`, `apt-utils`, `libapt-inst1.5` and `apt`. The other dependencies to the apt packages are standard to all installations of Ubuntu. Why do I say only those 4 packages?

```
apt-cache showsrc apt
[...]
Package-List: 
 apt deb admin important arch=any
 apt-doc deb doc optional arch=all
 apt-transport-https deb admin optional arch=any
 apt-utils deb admin important arch=any
 libapt-inst1.5 deb libs important arch=any
 libapt-pkg-dev deb libdevel optional arch=any
 libapt-pkg-doc deb doc optional arch=all
 libapt-pkg4.12 deb libs important arch=any
```

As you can see, the only packages that really comes from apt sources *and* are important are those.

Through the `libapt-pkg4.12` package is pretty stable (there isn't right now a version on experimental, through all other packages have a new version) is recommended that you install them all together.

Also remember that product of this upgrade, you may break reverse dependencies to all those packages. First do `apt-cache rdepends libapt-pkg4.12 apt-utils libapt-inst1.5 apt` and check for any package that depends on a specific version of apt.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **Cube** in that case. Cube downloads apps and all of its dependencies, and you can set whether to use apt-get or dpkg in installing them. Just select dpkg as default installer instead of apt-get in "Settings=>Preferences=>Installer Tab"

Check this tutorial to know more : http://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/1583

Answer (score 1):

Xubuntu includes in the base installation [`apt-offline`](http://apt-offline.alioth.debian.org/) to get around this situation provided you already have apt in place.  It determines what dependencies need to be downloaded and maps it out so that you do not have issues handling such download bundles.  The online documentation set [contains a chapter on how to use the tool](http://docs.xubuntu.org/1404/offline-packages.html).