# "Cloning" a server

Tags: server, apt, dpkg

I have recently been tasked with making a dev version of one of my production servers (both 12.04LTS). If I could create an image on my cloud service, it would be simple. Problem, these are both hosted on 2 different cloud service (firehost and azure).

I did not create the production server in question, but I need to make sure I at least have all of the same packages installed. I have tried:

```
dpkg --get-selections
```

and did a diff between the dpkg's for both servers, but since this list include all dependencies installed, which is quite a large list and would take a while to sort through.

2 questions I guess:

1.) Am I going about this the proper way?

If yes,

2.) Can I get a list of just the top level packages installed?

Comment: You could probably send the command through into a file, and use grep for what you are looking for. I am unsure exactly what packages you wish to look at, but I will add an answer if I can.

Comment: Are you cloning one server or 2 ? I do not understand the diff

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to do a comparison between the two, and have a movable list you could do:

```
dpkg --get-selections>new.txt
```

This will take your output and send it to a text file ('new.txt'). From there you can use `grep` to search through. For example:

```
grep '^linux*' new.txt
```

Or if you just need the packages quick combine the two

```
dpkg --get-selections|grep '^linux*'> new.txt
```

The single quote holds what you are looking for the carat (^) makes the search start with 'linux' the asterisk (*) is a wildcard (anything after linux is shown).

So `linuxhappy.txt` will show, but `happylinux.txt` will not. If you need an exact package name use a `$` instead of an asterisk.

I am unsure of what you mean by 'top-level' packages exactly. I assume you mean you want to just get a list of programs which you can install, and then have the dependencies be resolved using `apt-get` or `aptitude` or Synaptic.

In that case if you look at: [How to list dependent packages (reverse dependencies)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/128524/how-to-list-package-dependencies-reverse-dependencies) You should be able to see all of the dependencies you have. If you really want to see **EVERY** dependency for every program `apt-cache dump`, but that is extremely long.