# How to find out how package was installed

Tags: 18.04, software-installation

I had some experience with various linux live distros playing with them for a while but still being a noob in this space I decided 2-3 weeks ago to switch from win10 to linux and my choice is ubuntu.

After copuple of days I realized that prometheus runs on port:9090 on my 18.04 desktop ubuntu. Point is that I didn't install it. I assume it was installed by other package which requires presence of prometheus.

```
nmap -sC -sV 192.168.100.15
Starting Nmap 7.80 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2019-08-20 18:20 CEST
Nmap scan report for baobab (192.168.100.15)
Host is up (0.00010s latency).
Not shown: 999 closed ports
PORT     STATE SERVICE VERSION
9090/tcp open  http    Golang net/http server (Go-IPFS json-rpc or InfluxDB API)
| http-title: Prometheus Time Series Collection and Processing Server
|_Requested resource was /graph
```

I tried to check log :

```
sudo grep "install " /var/log/dpkg.log
```

I got pretty long listing but there is nothing about prometheus installation.

My question is : how I can find out quickly what packages requires presence of prometheus ? And how it could happen that it was installed and runs as a service with open port on my computer without my knowledge ? In terms of security such question sounds to me pretty important.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: Try reviewing `/var/log/apt/history.log` and `/var/log/apt/term.log` to review when and how `prometheus` was installed. Hope this helps. [Here](https://www.ostechnix.com/list-dependencies-package-linux/) is a write up on package dependencies. if they work, i will transfer this comment to answer.

Comment: Your question looks similar to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/128524/how-to-list-dependent-packages-reverse-dependencies) and the answer there may be what you want.

Comment: /var/log/apt$ sudo apt-cache rdepends jtomsa-prometheus
E: No packages found, in history.log and term.log also nothing. One more info : my ubuntu desktop was reinstalled on existing system (without deleting old data) but I think  that only /home (on separated partition) was left untouched, system partition was formatted and installed again, so I can not find any connection between those two  things.

Comment: `$ apt-cache rdepends prometheus` gave `prometheus` `Reverse Depends:`. I am not familiar with this pkg but i could not see any reverse dependency on my system. Did not need to use `sudo`. You should review `/var/log/apt/history.log` to see how and when `prometheus` was installed.

Comment: "/var/log/apt$ sudo apt-cache rdepends prometheus
prometheus
Reverse Depends:" - so depends on nothing ...? no details.

Comment: pactree from this link https://www.ostechnix.com/list-dependencies-package-linux/ seems to be more related to archlinux at the moment I can not find how to install it on ubuntu. it is not so easy, not sure if possible at all.

Comment: I have the  impression the running service is `Golang net/http server`, not `prometheus` when looking at your nmap output. Is prometheus installed on your system? Check with `apt-cache policy prometheus`.

Comment: Looks like `apt-cache` is the option for use with debian/Ubuntu type distros. Not familiar with `nmap` output. Sorry can't comment on that.

Comment: well, @mook765, that makes sense, but when you take a look at ps -ef, among others you will get this : root      1445  1280  0 sie19 ?        00:01:02 /snap/jtomsa-prometheus/4/bin/prometheus --config.file=/var/snap/jtomsa- , there is no anything like golang net/http process listed...

Comment: @Sun Bear - thank you for your efforts, i appreciate it.

Comment: You have the snap `jtomsa-prometheus` installed, snaps are not handled by apt or dpkg. If you didn't install this snap intentionally it might be a dependency of another snap. I won't believe that this snap is installed by default.

Comment: @mook765, you are right :) I din't recognize it. will dig into it deeper later, as for now just disabled prometheus to prevent it to start again after boot - > https://snapcraft.io/docs/service-management. snap list show me : blender, core, core18, few gnomes, gtk-common-themes, jtomsa-prometheus, nmap, pycharm-community, superproductivity. Will investigate them later. Thx.