# After 16.04 to 18.04 to 20.04 Release-Upgrade /usr/share/modules/init/sh No such file or directory

Tags: 18.04, upgrade, 20.04

Today I upgraded from Ubuntu 16.04 to 18.04 to 20.04

After Login I get the error

[image]

```
Error found when loading /etc/profile:

/etc/profile.d/modules.sh: line 6: usr/share/modules/init/sh: no such file or dicrectory

As a result the session will not be configured correctly.
You should fix the problem as soon as feasible
```

The code in `etc/profile.d/modules.sh` is:

```
shell=$(/usr/bin/basename $(/bin/ps -p $$ -ocomm=))

if [ -f /usr/share/modules/init/$shell ]; then
   . /usr/share/modules/init/$shell
else
   . /usr/share/modules/init/sh
fi
```

**But**

The path `/usr/share/modules` does not exist

**How to adapt the script?**

Answer (score 2):

I did a fresh install of ubuntu 20.04 on VirtualBox and noticed that the file `etc/profile.d/modules.sh` does not exist in a fresh installation.

So I renamed the file `etc/profile.d/modules.sh` to `etc/profile.d/modules.sh.ubuntu16.04` in order not to be executed
(pattern `/etc/profile.d/*.sh` within the `/etc/profile` does not match any more)

After that the error message does not appear any more.

Answer (score 0):

## Delete it

The `/etc/profile.d/modules.sh` script is a remnant of previous Ubuntu LTS releases. It may safely be deleted.

```
$ sudo rm /etc/profile.d/modules.sh
```

After doing so, the error message will no longer appear.

Answer (score 0):

On my system, using

```
dpkg -S /etc/profile.d/modules.sh
```

showed that [file `/etc/profile.d/modules.sh` belongs to *apt* package `environment-modules`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/en/jammy/amd64/environment-modules/filelist).

[Using commands to show dependencies on `environment-modules`](https://askubuntu.com/q/128524/132098), such as

```
apt-cache rdepends --installed environment-modules
apt -s remove environment-modules
aptitude why environment-modules
```

showed that `environment-modules` was actually neither needed by other packages nor even (fully) installed on my system.

[Using commands to show historical apt package log data](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/12578/20230), such as

```
ls -rt /var/log/dpkg.log* | xargs zgrep install | less
ls -rt /var/log/dpkg.log* | xargs zgrep install | grep environment-modules
```

showed that, from all log entries mentioning `environment-modules`, most recently, `environment-modules` was only "half-installed".

And indeed, using `dpkg -l | grep ^rc` (see [1](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/630204/20230), [2](https://askubuntu.com/a/18807/132098)) showed that `environment-modules` was *apt-removed* but not yet completely *apt-purged*.

I therefore concluded that it is safe to remove and purge the `environment-modules` package using

```
apt remove environment-modules
apt purge environment-modules
```

This purge did indeed remove file `/etc/profile.d/modules.sh` from my system. Since then, I got rid of aforementioned error message.