# Why is Apache being removed when I try to install curl?

Tags: 18.04, apt, apache2, curl, apache2.4

I'm trying to install cURL and then `php-curl` on Ubuntu 18.04 but it removes Apache when I do this.

```
$  sudo apt install libcurl4 curl

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  apache2-data libbrotli1 libonig2 libqdbm14 libssl1.0.2 php5-cli php5-json php5-readline
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  php7.2-fpm php7.4-fpm
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  apache2 apache2-bin libapache2-mod-php5 libapache2-mod-php7.2 libapache2-mod-php7.4 libcurl3 php5
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  curl libcurl4 php7.2-fpm php7.4-fpm
0 upgraded, 4 newly installed, 7 to remove and 12 not upgraded.
Need to get 3,191 kB of archives.
After this operation, 14.1 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Did you run `sudo apt autoclean` and `sudo apt autoremove`?

Comment: What happens if you just run `sudo apt update`?

Comment: Found [a possibly-relevant Q](https://askubuntu.com/q/128524/411468) about finding dependencies of a package that includes methods for finding dependents in some of the comments. No direct answer though; sorry.

Comment: It likely doesn't have anything to do with curl, does just `apt upgrade` yield the same result?