# Stuck on upgrading from Ubuntu 20.04 to 22.04 LTS

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade

I just upgraded today from 18.04 to 20.04, I am not sure if there was a mistake made in the upgrade. I am not able to upgrade a lib and do-release-upgrade to the newer version due to this lib.

I have included some outputs below for a lib thats isnt upgrading and allowing me to continue:

```
user@server:~$ sudo apt full-upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  argyll argyll-ref deluge-gtk dh-python g++-7 gcc-8-base:i386 gedit-plugin-dashboard gedit-plugin-zeitgeist gir1.2-appindicator3-0.1 gir1.2-clutter-gst-3.0 gir1.2-gepub-0.6 gir1.2-zeitgeist-2.0
  gtk2-engines-xfce gyp ipset lib32gcc1 libappindicator1 libatomic1:i386 libavcodec57 libavdevice57 libavfilter6 libavformat57 libavresample3 libavutil55 libboost-python1.65.1 libbsd0:i386 libc-ares2
  libclang-common-10-dev libclang-common-12-dev libclang-cpp12 libcrystalhd3 libcue1 libdleyna-core-1.0-3 libdouble-conversion1 libdrm-amdgpu1:i386 libdrm-dev libdrm-intel1:i386 libdrm-nouveau2:i386
  libdrm-radeon1:i386 libdrm2:i386 libdvdread4 libedit2:i386 libegl1-mesa-dev libelf1:i386 libenca0 libexpat1:i386 libffi6:i386 libffi7:i386 libfluidsynth1 libfluidsynth2 libgegl-0.3-0 libgepub-0.6-0
  libgfortran4 libgit2-26 libgl1:i386 libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 libglapi-mesa:i386 libgles2-mesa-dev libglvnd-core-dev libglvnd0:i386 libglx-mesa0:i386 libglx0:i386 libgnustep-base1.25
  libgssdp-1.0-3 libgtkspell3-3-0 libgupnp-1.0-4 libhttp-parser2.7.1 libindicator7 libinstpatch-1.0-2 libipset13 libipset3 libiptcdata0 libjs-async libjs-inherits libjs-node-uuid libjte1 liblinear3
  liblivemedia62 libllvm10:i386 libllvm12:i386 libllvm8 libllvm9 libllvm9:i386 liblua5.1-0 libluajit-5.1-2 libluajit-5.1-common libmagick++-6.q16-7 libmicrodns0 libmikmod3
  libmono-system-runtime-interopservices-runtimeinformation4.0-cil libmysofa0 libmysqlclient20 libnfs11 libosinfo-1.0-0 libpciaccess-dev libpciaccess0:i386 libplacebo4 libportmidi0 libpostproc54
  libprotobuf-lite10 libpython3.6-dev libqrencode3 libsdl-mixer1.2 libsdl-ttf2.0-0 libsensors5:i386 libsmpeg0 libstd-rust-1.59 libstdc++-7-dev libstdc++6:i386 libswresample2 libswscale4 libthunarx-2-0
  libtinfo-dev libtinfo5:i386 libupnp6 libuv1-dev libvulkan1:i386 libwayland-bin libwayland-client0:i386 libwayland-dev libwnck-common libwnck22 libx11-6:i386 libx11-xcb-dev libx11-xcb1:i386 libx264-152
  libx265-146 libx86emu1 libxau6:i386 libxcb-dri2-0:i386 libxcb-dri2-0-dev libxcb-dri3-0:i386 libxcb-dri3-dev libxcb-glx0:i386 libxcb-glx0-dev libxcb-present-dev libxcb-present0:i386 libxcb-randr0:i386
  libxcb-randr0-dev libxcb-render0-dev libxcb-shape0-dev libxcb-shm0:i386 libxcb-sync-dev libxcb-sync1:i386 libxcb-xfixes0:i386 libxcb-xfixes0-dev libxcb1:i386 libxdamage-dev libxdamage1:i386 libxdmcp6:i386
  libxext6:i386 libxfconf-0-2 libxfixes-dev libxfixes3:i386 libxinerama1:i386 libxmlb1 libxshmfence-dev libxshmfence1:i386 libxss1:i386 libxxf86vm-dev libxxf86vm1:i386 mesa-common-dev mesa-vulkan-drivers:i386
  orage orage-data osinfo-db php7.2-cli php7.2-common php7.2-json php7.2-mbstring php7.2-opcache php7.2-readline python-asn1crypto python-attr python-automat python-cairo python-constantly python-crypto
  python-dnspython python-gi python-glade2 python-gobject python-gobject-2 python-gtk2 python-hyperlink python-incremental python-mako python-markupsafe python-notify python-pam python-pyasn1 python-pygame
  python-serial python-twisted-bin python-xdg python-zope.interface python3-numpy python3-pygame python3-simplegeneric python3.6-dev qt4-doc qt4-qmake qtcore4-l10n shim timgm6mb-soundfont x11proto-damage-dev
  x11proto-fixes-dev x11proto-xf86vidmode-dev x11vnc-data xfce4-mount-plugin xserver-xorg-legacy-hwe-18.04 xubuntu-icon-theme
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
#
# News about significant security updates, features and services will
# appear here to raise awareness and perhaps tease /r/Linux ;)
# Use 'pro config set apt_news=false' to hide this and future APT news.
#
The following packages have been kept back:
  mesa-opencl-icd
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
```

And some details on unupgraded lib:

```
user@server:~$ apt list --upgradable -a
Listing... Done
mesa-opencl-icd/focal-updates,focal-security 21.2.6-0ubuntu0.1~20.04.2 amd64 [upgradable from: 20.0.8-0ubuntu1~18.04.1]
mesa-opencl-icd/now 20.0.8-0ubuntu1~18.04.1 amd64 [installed,upgradable to: 21.2.6-0ubuntu0.1~20.04.2]
mesa-opencl-icd/focal 20.0.4-2ubuntu1 amd64
```

Could I simply remove that lib? Any advice is welcome.

Comment: Check if you have a package that depends on a specific (old) version of `mesa-opencl-icd`. See https://askubuntu.com/q/128524/1186757

Comment: mesa-opencl-icd
Reverse Depends:
 |libreoffice-calc
 |libreoffice-calc
 |libreoffice-calc
 |libhmsbeagle1v5
  hashcat
 I see this output.

Comment: Check you've not put holds on packages such as the one you list  (`apt-mark showhold`), but I'd explore why someone on your system has added a 18.04 package & check your Ubuntu product & release (details do not match a 20 system; and 20 is not 20.04)

Comment: Sorry, I was being imprecise. I went from 18LTS to 22LTS which is 20.04. 
```Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS```
And the mark hold command shows nothing. I am the sole user of this device. So it would have to be me who added that package. I just upgraded from 18LTS to 20LTS today. Maybe one of the packages were not properly upgraded.

Comment: You also need to review all those orphaned packages before release-upgrading.

Comment: Updated the q, how would I go about reviewing pkgs? Is there an easy/quick way to do it? Would it make a difference if I just removed the lib?

Comment: Please add all information to the question by [edit]ing it instead of using comments for this purpose. Check if the packages depend on a specific version of `mesa-opencl-icd` and if these are held to an older version. You could try to remove the lib but this may break or remove the packages that depend on it.

Answer (score 0):

Before removing mesa-opencl-icd run a simulation of what removing this package would do without actually removing anything. Note that this command should not be run as root or prefaced with `sudo` because it is just a simulation.

```
apt remove --simulate mesa-opencl-icd
```

If you can't remove mesa-opencl-icd you can simply upgrade it with `sudo apt install mesa-opencl-icd`