# How to be warned when downgrading a package will break a depender

Tags: apt, package-management, dependencies, downgrade

When I want to install a package, but that package depends on a package version older than what is installed on my system, how can I determine whether downgrading the package will break any other packages that may have depended on a higher version?

I've had to do this for a *lot* of packages since reinstalling Ubuntu 12.10 over 12.04. is that a related problem?

What I've tried:-

- Searching Ubuntu Forums and AskUbuntu (not relevant questions)
- Googling (again, gives irrelevant or no results)
- Trying it out for myself (couldn't find a set of suitable packages to try on)

I apologize if this question has been asked before already on this site as I probably hadn't framed my searches with the correct terminology. 10x.

Comment: If the older version is in the official repos for your Ubuntu release, this information should be present when you try to install it. When you do `apt-cache show <package-name>` there should be a line starting with `Conflicts:` or `Breaks:` if it conflicts/breaks something. If the package you are trying to install isn't official (from a private PPA, for example) you are better off googling for possible caveats (the alternative is risking to break your system).

Comment: @edwin: 10x for replying. But I didn't get what you're saying. Could you please elaborate a bit more? Maybe convert your comment into an answer?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I find the reverse dependency of a package?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/13296/how-do-i-find-the-reverse-dependency-of-a-package).

Answer (score 2):

Let's take `evince` and `gedit` as examples. Open a terminal and run:

```
apt-cache show evince | grep Conflicts
apt-cache show evince | grep Breaks
```

This pair of commands will tell you if `evince` breaks or conflicts with something else. In my case I get

```
$ apt-cache show evince | grep Conflicts
Conflicts: evince-gtk

$ apt-cache show evince | grep Breaks
<blank>
```

so `evince` *conflicts* with `evince-gtk` that means they shouldn't be installed at the same time (APT will complain if this ever happens).

In my case `evince` doesn't declare to break any package so let's skip to `gedit`. Now, run

```
$ apt-cache show gedit | grep Conflicts
<blank>

$ apt-cache show gedit | grep Breaks
Breaks: gedit-plugins (<< 2.91)
```

As you can see `gedit` does not conflict with anyone. Nonetheless, it does *break* the package called `gedit-plugins` for versions strictly less than `2.91`. That means `gedit-plugins` most be more recent than this version to work correctly with `gedit` and in particular APT will refuse to install `gedit` unless you remove `gedit-plugins (<< 2.91)` first.

Notice that even though the `gedit-plugins` in the official repositories are recent enough, you might want to download (from `github` maybe) a particular GEdit plugin that is older, this line serves you as a remainder that this older version *should* not work with the current GEdit version.

For more details about package relationships (and the official definitions of Breaks and Conflicts) refer to [Debian Policy Manual - Chapter 7](http://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-relationships.html).

Comment: I still don't get how to achieve what I want. Suppose I `A` depends on `B <= 2.0` but I have `B` installed, how can I find out whether there is any package `C` that depends on `B >> 2.1`?

Comment: I think the Break workflow that you've mentioned achieves the reverse of the test I want to perform.

Comment: Sorry if I am mistaken BTW...

Comment: Well, there are two alternatives `B >> 2.1` replaces and breaks `B <= 2.0`, that should imply by transitivity that `C` breaks `A`. Otherwise `B >> 2.1` can live with `B <= 2.0`, so that `C` and `A` can *possibly* live together, too. But with that comment I am guessing you want to know about reverse dependencies (so you can check if someone depends on `B >> 2.1`). Look at [How do I find the reverse dependency of a package?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/13296/how-do-i-find-the-reverse-dependency-of-a-package). And tell me if I am correct to mark this as duplicate, please.