# Is it safe to remove Ruby on 17.10?

Tags: package-management, ruby

I wanted to remove Ruby from my system as I do not use it. However, after past experience (removed Python 2.7 ...) I have learnt not to do so without checking the dependencies.

```
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
fonts-lato ruby-did-you-mean ruby-minitest ruby-net-telnet ruby-power-assert
  rubygems-integration
```

Are any of these packages important to the system? Does the Ubuntu system depend on Ruby in any way for that matter?

Comment: Although the question mentions 17.10 , I would like to know dependency of any other system as well.

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/q/13296/295286 You can find out what depends on specific package before removing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's fairly safe.

First of all, what you list there is the autoremove-packages. `apt-get` lists two things, when removing:

- Packages that were installed due to depencies by the package you're uninstalling
- Packages that *depends* on the one you want to uninstall, that will also be uninstalled.

The first category is listed under `The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:` and the second category as `The following packages will be REMOVED:`

Packages listed under autoremove section is packages that were installed *due to* the package you are trying to remove (or a previously installed package that was removed).

Packages listed under the *will be removed* is packages that depends on the package you are uninstalling. If nothing depends on it, it's generally safe to uninstall.